# Linear mixed model high AIC

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, aic, blue

I try to create a Linear mixed model by comparing different combinations of random effects. However my AIC score is much higher then I find in tutorials (best 6541.42). Can I still use such a model to calculate the BLUEs (Best linear unbiased estimators)? Are there any alternatives?

[image]

Edit:

Looking at the histogram of the data it looks pretty normal distributed except for the zero values, I have a lot of samples (not outliers) with 0 % phenotype:

[image]

Questions:

1. How to deal with this? Can I still use linear mixed models to calculate the adjusted mean of phenotype repetitions in different environments?
2. According to the QQ plot, is it correct that the very low and very high phenotype values will lead inaccurate predicted BLUEs values?
3. Is there another method to get the adjusted mean value of phenotype repetitions in different environments? Coming from the ML and DL field, try and error modeling with different environmental parameters feels kind of "strange".
4. How to deal with datasets which are by purpose as much diverse as possible, so there are for sure not normally distributed but the controls are. Is it still correct to use the same model (same experimental setup as above)?

Answer (score 1):

The AIC score is not supposed to lie in any fixed interval universally across data sets and models. It inherits this property from the (log-) likelihood as AIC is simply twice the negative log-likelihood adjusted for degrees of freedom, $$\text{AIC}=2k-2\ln(L).$$
Thus a value of $6541.42$ does not seem problematic in general.

Comment: While you are not asking about the QQ plot you have included, it indicates the errors do not follow the assumed Normal distribution. If you care about inference, you may wish to consider a different model or a different distributional assumption. Otherwise, inference that depends on the normality assumption may be invalid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I updated my question for more details and question. If I Understand correctly, the AIC score is rather used to compare models with different formulas?

Comment: @snowflake, yes, AIC is primarily used for model comparison. At the same time AIC is an estimate of twice the negativ expected likelihood on a new data points, thus an estimate of expected predictive performance.